# Is there a way to choose a different column on a comparison based on a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first question here and I hope you guys can help me with this.
I'm trying to make a view based on a table that has the following columns: `DAY_0`, `DAY_1`, `DAY_2`, `DAY_3`, `DAY_4`, `DAY_5`, `DAY_6`.
The problem is that I only want to compare the column based on the actual day and see if it return the value `0` or `1`.
I was thinking on something like this but didn't work:

```
WHERE 'DAY_'+weekday(curdate()) = 1
```

Anyone knows how to help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function

```
ELT(weekday(curdate())+1,DAY_0,DAY_1,..)
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable column names like that, but you could do something like this:

```
WHERE
    CASE WEEKDAY(CURDATE())
        WHEN 0 THEN DAY_0
        WHEN 1 THEN DAY_1
        ...
    END CASE = 1
```

You might also want to look into database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

but you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 0 THEN day_0
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 1 THEN day_1
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 2 THEN day_2
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 3 THEN day_3
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 4 THEN day_4
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 5 THEN day_5
     WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = 6 THEN day_6
  END AS theDay

FROM myTable;
```